# Speedup LocalSessionFactoryBean dropDatabaseSchema, createDatabaseSchema

Tags: hibernate, spring, junit, hsqldb

I am wondering how I can speedup my unit tests.  I am using JUnit and before each test I am dropping the database schema and then recreating it.  Since my schema is somewhat large, this can take quite a long time considering I have over 1000 tests.

To give you an understanding of my setup:
  Spring 3 hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean which is using the HSQL dialect.
  I am using the JUnit's Suite runner to run a list of classes.

I noticed that Spring has a SpringJunit4ClassRunner that understands Transaction annotation, but not the suite annotations.  I got around this issue and now rollbacks are being attempted, but they seem to cause an infinite recursion which leads to a StackOverflow.

I'm relatively new to Spring and all it's magic, but I was just wondering if anyone has any ideas in regard to the StackOverflow, or any other ideas in speeding up the testing?

Maybe I could write to a file the clean state of the DB and continuously reload that after each test, though I'm not sure if this is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HSQLDB 2.2.6 supports a statement to clear the data in a database schema.

```
   TRUNCATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AND COMMIT
```

See the guide here:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_truncate_statement

Version 2.2.7 and later supports `TRUNCATE SCHEMA PUBLIC RESTART IDENTITY AND COMMIT`

Comment: This works wonderfully, and is much simpler than trying to rollback the transactions. Thanks a whole bunch.

Comment: One more thing, is there any way of reset the auto_increment field for every table?  Truncating doesn't seem to do this.

Comment: Actually it should reset the identity, but it doesn't. Will be fixed in the next release. For a table, `TRUNCATE TABLE mytable RESTART IDENTITY AND COMMIT` does it.

Comment: Sweet, I guess this is a good enough reason to makes my test independent of the ids.

Comment: From version 2.2.7, TRUNCATE SCHEAME supports resetting the auto-increment fields.

Answer (score 1):

If what is taking the time is creating the schema, use the suggestion made by fredt.

If creating the data is taking the time (rather than the schema), then I would go for your final suggestion, to create a 'standard' database which is used for all of your tests, at least as the base. This is what I do in some of my projects.

I have a database.script file somewhere in my source tree. In my test setup `@Before`, I copy the file into a temporary directory. My spring configuration points to this copy. The copy avoids changing the standard database. Then in the `@After`, I do shutdown, and delete the file [*]. Using `@Before` and `@After` is a pain if you've got the same code everywhere, so look at [ExternalResource](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/ExternalResource.html), which is a [TestRule](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TestRule.html) which allows you to implement before/after logic but in a nice, factored manner.

If I'm using maven, the target for the copy is usually target/temp/something. This way all of the copies get removed with an `mvn clean`.

[*] This works well under linux, but under windows, the files sometimes fail to delete, so I either move the file to a temp name, or use one file per test. You can get a name using the [TestName](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TestName.html) rule.

Comment: If you use the property files_readonly=true in the .properties file of your database, or on the connection URL, then no change will be written to the .script file (or other files) and you don't need to copy it after each test.

Comment: I really do like your suggestion, but in my case not much data was being written each time and Fredt's solution works best.